# I have to sort the students record firstly level wise then name wise

Tags: c

The code I have made is as follow...but it is not sorting the result at all.it is just printing the same as it is input. Please help me out

```
     strcpy(newnode->stud_name,name);
strcpy(newnode->stud_intake,id);
strcpy(newnode->stud_branch,course);
newnode->level=slevel;
newnode->next=NULL;


if(list==NULL)
    list=newnode;
else 
{
    if(slevel==list->level)
    {
        temp=list;          
        placefound=0;
    while(temp!=NULL && slevel==temp->level)
    {
            if(name>temp->stud_name)
            {
                prev=temp;
                temp=temp->next;
            }//else
            //placefound=1;
    }
            newnode->next=prev->next;
            prev->next=newnode;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket; look at your `if(slevel==list->level)` statement, and add the closing `}` in the correct location.

Answer (score 6):

Without trying to debug your linked list code in detail, there's one very suspicious point:

```
if(name>temp->stud_name)
```

is probably wrong -- you can't compare C strings with ">". Look up how to use the "strcmp" function in the C standard library.